# joblib parallel_backend with dask resources

Tags: python, dask, joblib

Whenever I submit a `dask` task, I can specify the requisite resources for that task.  e.g. `client.submit(process, d, resources={'GPU': 1})`

However, If I abstract my `dask` scheduler away as a `joblib.parallel_backend`, it is not clear how to specify resources when I do so.

How do I call `joblib.parallel_backend('dask')` and still specify requisite resources?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-02-19, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Any update on this?   Is this possible now?